# Error running nativescript on ios but xcode runs successfully

Tags: ios, clang, nativescript, arm64

Tried to run the nativescript app using "tns run ios" and get the following error.

```
Saving metadata generation's stderr stream to: /...../platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-generation-stderr-x86_64.txt
~/work/qoo/qoo/platforms/ios
ld: in /Users/..../platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_8094107d82c527bf23f93e98c9db96d1.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/...../platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

However if i run the generated .xcworkspace project on iphone 11 pro max... the app starts up just fine.